# What navigation component to use in react-native for IOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I thought navigation-experimental was the latest one and I saw some posts which says it is deprecated in V0.43. So which navigation component to use in IOS, If I want to start today ?

**Update:**

There is no right answer to this question. But personally I prefer **react-native-router-flux**. But there are too many ones which makes difficult to choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). I hav not tried it yet personally but it seems promising.

Comment: Ya, This looks promising!!, but shouldn't I worry about navigation-experimental ? And, one more concern is, I want to use redux

Comment: You need to read [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) for redux. I do not have the experience to guide you which one is better or not. I saw the depreciation comments of nav-experimental of version `0.43` but for me personally we have to wait some more to worry about navigation-experimental. Because `0.42` documentation still says `If you are looking for greater control over your navigation stack, you can't go wrong with NavigationExperimental.`

Comment: Ya That is true!! Check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/08dbc43fa64ff1dfc0d364b6cef6262426f76b64 new readme out!!

Comment: Seems that starting from `0.43` and on they are supporting react-navigation which I mentioned in my answer in the first place. Thanks for pointing out the new readme!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one - https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation.
It has good API and is well maintained.

I haven't used it myself though. The one I use is https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: I have used react-router for the web ? Can you tell me how can it be used in the mobile ? I mean, is there any conceptual difference ?

Comment: I haven't got any experience with react-router, but react-native-router-flux is similar to it in terms of API. You nest the scenes in hierarchal order in the root, and calls the api to switch the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get started is on Exponent. Ex-navigation is great for beginners.